# How to design a simple economic model for a Martian settlement?

Tags: economy, worldbuilding-resources

I'm trying to design an economic model for my story world, starting from an individual settlement on Mars, then level by level, stepping up to one encompassing the entire Solar System. Aspects I'm interested in are what people live there, how they earn their income, where they spend it and thus, what businesses are there and how money circulates.

This is one of the first permanent human settlements on Mars.

Most people living there are scientists working for research projects funded by ESA, NASA, JAXA, other Earth-based Space agency, or some other scientific institution.

Another large group is engineers working to maintain necessary infrastructure and provide services like transportation. Usually works for a company subordinated to the settlement's administrative body.

Then there are private enterprises providing food and other goods, either locally produced or imported from other settlements/Earth, building residential housing and offices and then renting those to households or businesses respectively, etc.

At each institution, there is also a certain number of administrative staff. I'm assuming a proportion of 1:5, meaning that if University employs 500 researchers, it also employs 100 administrative personnel. Of course, those may overlap, i.e., a researcher may also work in an administrative position.

My question is:

**How to draw a model representing it?**

It should be reasonably comprehensive, simple to understand without advanced knowledge of economics, and fairly easy to create and adjust.

Comment: Without *advanced* knowledge of economics it might be possible, but I'm afraid that it is not possible with zero knowledge about how an economy works. Sorry, but Economics 101 is a full-year course. Ah, and for 100 researchers a research institution will likely employ some 300 or 400 administrative, technical and support personnel. (Personal peeve: What's this thing with *drawing* models? What's wrong with words and tables? Drawings are hard to interpret, hard to search, hard to update and hard to verify.)

Comment: "Drawings are hard to interpret, hard to search, hard to update and hard to verify.)" I mean graphical representation, i.e., a flowchart displaying data gathered in a table.

Comment: "Model" is not meant in the professional sense of economic modelling but rather a way to understand how the economy works and develops in this fictional world.

Comment: A note: your story world may not even need this information. Unless it's relevant for the story, just act as if things are just as they should be (or not as they should be if that is part of the story).

Comment: If you are just looking for cheap software to draw a flowchart, the free [Diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/) springs to mind.

Comment: What you're proposing is basically a city based around a research plant, which has happened many times on Earth - you could look at [Los Alamos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Alamos_National_Laboratory) as an example.

Comment: @AlexP I already have MS Excel on my computer. I'm looking for a way to systemise information to identify and represent relationships in the economic ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

## What you're talking about is called an organizational chart

A lot of companies and other organizations use professional software like [Lucidchart](https://lucid.app/pricing/lucidchart?km_CPC_AdGroupID=54511345905&utm_source=google&km_CPC_CampaignId=1391679521&_gl=1*1f3tmot*_ga*NDUyOTA5MC4xNjg0MzM0OTgy*_ga_MPV5H3XMB5*MTY4NDMzNDk4Mi4xLjAuMTY4NDMzNDk4Mi42MC4wLjA.*_gcl_aw*R0NMLjE2ODQzMzQ5ODUuQ2p3S0NBanc5cEdqQmhCLUVpd0FhNWpsM0oyN015YXdXMlY4OE83WUZNQ0piMVFRUGFwU3JoYng4V24xTXVQUGIxemFBak1sWXVTb3J4b0NMTElRQXZEX0J3RQ..&km_CPC_MatchType=b&km_CPC_Country=9051778&km_CPC_Keyword=%2Borganisation%20%2Bchart%20%2Bsoftware&gclid=CjwKCAjw9pGjBhB-EiwAa5jl3J27MyawW2V88O7YFMCJb1QQPapSrhbx8Wn1MuPPb1zaAjMlYuSorxoCLLIQAvD_BwE&km_CPC_Creative=442345699167&sessionDate=2023-05-17T14%3A49%3A58.524Z&km_CPC_TargetID=kwd-21285354265&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lucidchart.com%2Fpages%2Flanding%2Forg-charts-software&utm_medium=cpc&km_CPC_target=&km_CPC_Device=c&anonId=0.620f6f011882a30317b&km_CPC_AdPosition=&km_CPC_ExtensionID=&km_CPC_Network=g&sessionId=0.5d5be35b1882a30317d&utm_campaign=_chart_en_us_desktop_search_strategic_phrase_&km_CPC_placement=#/pricing/chart) to make this type of representational model of their administrative organization. There is a limited use free version of this software on their website. Another free option is [Google Drawings](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-drawings/mkaakpdehdafacodkgkpghoibnmamcme?hl=en-US) which can do a pretty good job of making these charts as well.

Comment: [Diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/) is much better than G Draw, in my opinion.

Comment: No, what I'm looking for is a way to specify and graphically represent information like: there is this number of people doing this job and earning this amount of money coming from this source; then they spend this amount on these goods buying them from these businesses; these businesses buy materials from these businesses and pay this amount in salaries to this number of workers, and taxes to this institution...

Comment: @KrišjānisLiepiņš that just sounds like flowchart with edge weights. https://www.mural.co/use-case/diagramming is a fairly straightforward tool, although I have not personally used it myself.